# What is 装 and 连 doing in this paragraph about a newt in a glass from Matilda? E.g. 她再看那装着蝾螈的玻璃杯

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context

This is from the Chinese version of Matilda (p.182):

> 那[蝾螈](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%9D%BE%E8%9E%88)仍旧在那个高玻璃杯**装**的水里扭来扭去，看起来让人极不舒服。杯子对它来说太小了。玛帝尔达看着特朗奇布尔，她多么恨她呀。她再看那**装**着蝾螈的玻璃杯，恨不得跑过去把它拿起来**连**蝾螈带水[泼](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B3%BC)在特朗奇布尔的头上。她想到她真这样做了的话特朗奇布尔会怎样对待她，不禁发起抖来。

The original English is:

> The newt was still squirming in the tall glass of water.  It looked horribly uncomfortable.  The glass was not big enough for it.  Matilda glared at the Trunchbull.  How she hated her.  She glared at the glass with the newt in it.  She longed to march up and grab the glass and tip the contents, newt and all, over the Trunchbull's head.  She trembled to think what the Trunchbull would do to her if she did that.

I understand it mostly, but don't understand the function of 装 and 连.

**Question**: What is 装 and 连 doing in this paragraph?

Comment: I know I’ve said it before but I really don’t believe that this is a good translation to go through. It reads like something written in *Englinese* and some of the translated sentences are just plain unfaithful to the original text.

Comment: I’m aware, but I’m determined to finish the book. I’m getting there!

Comment: Alright. Try not to pick up any bad habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

装 means contain, therefore 她再看那装着蝾螈的玻璃杯 means

> She glared at the glass with the newt **(contained) in** it.

Here 连 means together with, therefore 恨不得跑过去把它拿起来连蝾螈带水泼在特朗奇布尔的头上 means

> She longed to march up and grab the glass and tip the contents, **(with)** newt and all, over the Trunchbull's head

Answer (score 1):

装：  贮放;藏 hold, store

那蝾螈仍旧在那个高玻璃杯装的水里扭来扭去,
the salamander was still in the tall glass beaker, twisting and turning in the water,

连带：互相关连（关联）

恨不得跑过去把它拿起来连蝾螈带水泼在特朗奇布尔的头上。
(she) wished she could take the beaker and throw its contents in Trunchbull's face

把它拿起来连蝾螈带水
 take the beaker and its (related) contents

Oh Trunchbull, you're so sexy!